# c++ how to convert a character to hex

Tags: c++, hex

I know that when outputting hex I can use

```
cout<<hex<<(unsigned int)(unsigned char)ch<<endl
```

but I am getting a character from standard input by using

```
cin.read((char*)&ch , sizeof(unsigned char))
```

how do I change `ch` to `hex` this time?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert it to a `string`?

Comment: you shouldn't need to cast twice on the cout line, if at all

Answer (score 3):

```
cin.read((char*)&ch , sizeof(unsigned char));
cout << hex << (unsigned int)(ch) << endl;
```

should work.

Comment: I need to convert ch to hex not output it to hex

Comment: it is already in hex/decimal/binary/octal/whatever number system you want. what do you want to do with it after converting it into hex?

Comment: no but anything numeric you want to do with it works regardless of base (its almost certainly actually in base 2) you generally only need to convert for output

Answer (score 1):

Hex is fundamentally just a number, so the main consideration is checking the character is in fact hex and then performing a basic math operation to convert it to its binary representation.

```cpp
uint8_t constexpr NOT_HEX = -1;
uint8_t char_to_hex(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return c - '0';
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 10;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return c - 'A' + 10;
    return NOT_HEX;
}
```

<sub>NB: You will need to handle bit shifting the hex if it is a multi-character hex number</sub>

Comment: Obviously this is well past useful for OP, I am putting the answer here for future readers

Answer (score -1):

if you're trying to convert a single char to hex to do math with if for example, you can convert the ascii char representation to it's actual digit with a statement like:

```
char x = 'A';
int y = x;
if(y > 47 && y < 58)  //this covers 0-9
   y = y - 48;
else if (y > 64 && y < 71) // this covers A-F
   y = y - 55;
```

and use y as your new number. If you need to do it for more then one digit you can place this in a loop.